# ¿Cómo redondear "correctamente" en python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, matemáticas, redondeo

Acabo de descubrir que:

```
round(3.5) = 4
```

mientras que:

```
round(2.5) = 2
```

Es decir, cuando un nº **acaba en .5** a veces redondea hacia arriba (como debe ser) y otras hacia abajo.

Quiero hacer un programa que haga unos cálculos, pero los redondee bien, no me vale que **55.5** lo redondee a **55**.

¿Como puedo hacer para que dado un nº cualquiera me redondee bien los números que acaban en **.5**?

No me vale `ceil` porque si el nº es **2.4 redondearía a 3**, lo cual tampoco es correcto.

No quiero saber por qué pasa esto, quiero saber como hacer que un código como este funcione bien:

**X=a*b**, siendo *a y b 2 numeros decimales*
`print(round(X))` para que el usuario vea el número redondeado, así parece sencillo, pero si da **14.5 me redondea a 14**. Y eso no es redondear correctamente en ciencia.

Comment: lo siento por la edición, pero no quiero saber por qué, eso ya lo averigüé. Quiero saber como redondear correctamente. Si existe una funcion que redondee bien(es decir, si el nº acaba en .5 redondee hacia arriba, o si tengo que programar una función yo mismo, y cómo sería.

Comment: He publicado [¿Por qué en Python 3 round() redondea 3.5 a 4 pero 2.5 a 2?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/317012/83) como extensión de esta pregunta, centrándome en el _por qué_ en lugar del cómo hacer para que redondee de una u otra forma.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Te dejo dos soluciones:

## 1. Usar el paquete Decimal

```
from decimal import Decimal, ROUND_HALF_UP

def round_well(num):
    return Decimal(num).quantize(0, ROUND_HALF_UP)
```

## 2. Usar el paquete Math

```
import math
#Combinando ceil, para que salga de forma correcta

def round_well(n):
    if n - math.floor(n) < 0.5:
        return math.floor(n)
    return math.ceil(n)
```

Comment: lo de if n-math.floor(n)<0.5 no lo habia pensado

Comment: Sí, te lo puse también porque hay personas que no les gusta el Output de Decimal, por el tipo de número! Yo como tuve el mismo problema, tengo esta función en una biblioteca que me hice para mí :). Me alegro de haberte ayudado!

Answer (score 14):

Por qué esto ocurre está explicado en [¿Por qué en Python 3 round() redondea 3.5 a 4 pero 2.5 a 2?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/317012/83). Básicamente, Python 3 utiliza el [*bankers rounding*](https://wiki.c2.com/?BankersRounding), es decir, el redondeo del banquero, consistente en redondear los `.5` al número par más cercano.

---

Si quieres controlar exactamente qué redondeo aplicas, usa el módulo [`decimal`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/decimal.html) con sus opciones `ROUND_HALF_EVEN`, `ROUND_HALF_UP` o `ROUND_HALF_DOWN` ([hay más](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/decimal.html#rounding-modes)):

```
>>> decimal.Decimal('2.5').quantize(
         decimal.Decimal('1'), rounding=decimal.ROUND_HALF_EVEN
)
Decimal('2')

>>> decimal.Decimal('3.5').quantize(
         decimal.Decimal('1'), rounding=decimal.ROUND_HALF_EVEN
)
Decimal('4')

>>> decimal.Decimal('3.5').quantize(
         decimal.Decimal('1'), rounding=decimal.ROUND_HALF_DOWN
)
Decimal('3')

>>> decimal.Decimal('3.5').quantize(
         decimal.Decimal('1'), rounding=decimal.ROUND_HALF_UP
)
Decimal('4')
```

Comment: lo siento, pero editaron la pregunta y el "por qué" no es lo que yo pregunto (se que es cosas de los ordenadores y ya, me da igual). Quiero saber cómo hacer que mi programa redondee bien.

Comment: en la parte final de mi respuesta lo explico

Comment: ok, gracias, entonces la respuesta es usar el .quantize. Aunque veo que eso da un objeto de tipo decimal, asi que es posible que sea necesario pasarlo a int.

Comment: mejor desacepta mi respuesta que publicaré una pregunta ad hoc sobre el tema, si es que quieres ceñirte al redondeo de esta forma. Así podré eliminar esta respuesta. Gracias!

Comment: creo que es la mejor respuesta, seria una pena borrarla (aunque acortandola para que sea mas preciso)

Comment: @DavidMartínez ya edité para simplificar.

Comment: @fedorqui me *obligas* amigo a caer en el voto serial positivo a ti, espero no me regañen pero entre este aporte y la otra publicación que hiciste hay mucho conocimiento que merece ser premiado, eso sin contar que para mí está debería ser la respuesta aceptada

Comment: @Aprendiz tus palabras me honran. Espero que el detector de votos seriales sea magnánimo :)

Comment: me gustaria aceptar las 2, la otra comenta también el quantize y otro metodo que devuelve un entero

Answer (score 3):

Puedes revisar la parte entera del número y en base a eso decidir redondear hacia arriba o dejarlo como está.

En el caso que termine el número con .5, `round` decide redondear hacia el número al número par más cercano, si es impar la parte entera, redondea al número par menor más cercano. Por lo tanto, si el numero es impar, redondear hacia arriba, de lo contrario dejarlo como está.

O puedes optar por la otra solución que es revisar la parte decimal, si es igual a 5, simplemente redondear hacia arriba.

En código sería

```
num = 8.9
float, int = math.modf(num) # regresa la parte entera y decimal

# opción 1
if not int % 2:
    num = ceil(num)

# opción 2
if float == 0.5:
     num = ceil(num)
```

Comment: es decir, que toca programar a mano el redondeo. Me sorprende que no hayan "inventado" la función

Comment: @DavidMartínez como te dije, en mi respuesta indico cómo se puede hacer utilizando módulos ya existentes

Comment: Benjamin: estás redefiniendo builtins como `float` o `int`, ¡cuidado!

Answer (score 0):

La verdad es que parece bastante raro... Puedes probar a controlarlo con un `if(charAt(num) == '.5')` y que te haga un redondeo forzado hacia arriba con lo siguiente:

```
import math
math.ceil(num)
```

Comment: es que quiero que redondee bien, si fuerzo ya no esta redondeando bien.

Answer (score 0):

He consultado este hilo para resolver las dudas sobre el redondeo de los tipos en coma flotante en Python. Y las contestaciones me han sido bastante útiles. No obstante al hacer comprobaciones resultaba que se producían ciertos efectos indeseados. Parece que cuando se convierte un float en decimal, es el valor BINARIO de ese float, el que se transforma en un decimal. Y esto por lo general no tiene más importancia, pero esa conversión arrastra una serie de cifras por encima del decimal número 15. Por ello,  sugiero primero, en la función definida indicada por los compañeros, antes del redondeo deseado, realizar una conversión controlada desestimando los decimales de ruido que trae la conversión.

```
from decimal import *
def round_hup(num, dec:int=None):
    if dec is None or dec == 0: dec=0
    else:
        if dec > 28 - str(num).find('.'): dec = 28 - str(num).find('.')
        dec = Decimal('1.' + dec * '0')
    if type(num) is Decimal:
        d = num 
    elif type(num) is float: 
        d = Decimal(num).quantize(Decimal('1.' + 14 * '0'), ROUND_HALF_UP) 
    else: 
        d = Decimal(num) #conversión de num en decimal
    return Decimal(d).quantize(dec, ROUND_HALF_UP) #devolver num redondeado
```

Cualquier comentario, corrección o sugerencia se agradece.