# ¿Por qué en Python 3 round() redondea 3.5 a 4 pero 2.5 a 2?

Tags: python, python-3.x, matemáticas, redondeo

Resulta que:

```
>>> round(3.5)
4
```

Mientras que:

```
>>> round(2.5)
2
```

Es decir, cuando un número acaba en .5 a veces redondea hacia arriba (como debe ser) y otras hacia abajo.

¿Por qué pasa esto? ¿Cómo puedo *forzar* a Python para que redondee de una forma determinada?

<sub>Esta es una *fork* de la pregunta [¿Cómo redondear "correctamente" en python?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/316983/83), pues surge un tema que considero relevante pero que no es esencial para el autor. Para no *estropear* su pregunta, creo una nueva</sub>.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Python 3 utiliza el [*bankers rounding*](https://wiki.c2.com/?BankersRounding), es decir, el redondeo del banquero, consistente en redondear los `.5` al número par más cercano:

```
>>> round(0.5)
0
>>> round(1.5)
2
>>> round(2.5)
2
>>> round(3.5)
4
>>> round(4.5)
4
```

Esto es nuevo en Python 3, como se ve en [*What's new in Python 3.0*](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.0.html#builtins):

> The [`round()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#round) function rounding strategy and return type have changed. Exact halfway cases are now rounded to the nearest even result instead of away from zero. (For example, `round(2.5)` now returns `2` rather than `3`.) `round(x[, n])` now delegates to `x.__round__([n])` instead of always returning a float. It generally returns an integer when called with a single argument and a value of the same type as `x` when called with two arguments.

Es decir:

> La estrategia de redondeo y de tipo de retorno de la función [`round()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#round) han cambiado. Los casos *a medio camino* se redondean ahora al resultado par más cercano, en lugar de hacia arriba. (Por ejemplo, `round(2.5)` ahora devuelve `2` en lugar de `3`.) `round(x[, n])` ahora delega en `x.__round__([n])` en lugar de devolver siempre un float. Generalmente devuelve un entero cuando se le llama con un único argumento y un valor del mismo tipo que `x` cuando se le llama con dos argumentos.

Si te preguntas por qué, de forma contraintuitiva, luego ocurre que con decimales esta regla no ocurre...

```
>>> round(2.235, 2)
2.23
>>> round(2.245, 2)
2.25
```

En la página del builtin [`round()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#round) se lee luego:

> Note The behavior of `round()` for floats can be surprising: for example, `round(2.675, 2)` gives `2.67` instead of the expected `2.68`. This is not a bug: it’s a result of the fact that most decimal fractions can’t be represented exactly as a float. See [Floating Point Arithmetic: Issues and Limitations](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/floatingpoint.html#tut-fp-issues) for more information.

Es decir:

> Nótese que el comportamiento de `round()` para números con decimales puede ser sorprendente: por ejemplo, `round(2.675, 2)` devuelve `2.67` en lugar del `2.68` esperado. Esto no es un bug: es el resultado del hecho que la mayoría de las fracciones decimales no se pueden representar exactamente como un float. Lee [Floating Point Arithmetic: Issues and Limitations](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/floatingpoint.html#tut-fp-issues) para tener más información.

---

La idea de que redondear .5 al entero superior no es correcta *per se*. Como se puede leer en [esta respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10825998/1983854) a [Python 3.x rounding behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10825926/1983854):

> The simple "always round 0.5 up" technique results in a slight bias toward the higher number. With large numbers of calculations, this can be significant. The Python 3.0 approach eliminates this issue.

Y luego indica que hay cinco posibles tipos de redondeo descritos en [IEEE 754.](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=IEEE_754#Rounding_rules)

---

Si quieres controlar exactamente qué redondeo aplicas, usa el módulo [`decimal`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/decimal.html) con sus opciones `ROUND_HALF_EVEN`, `ROUND_HALF_UP` o `ROUND_HALF_DOWN` ([hay más](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/decimal.html#rounding-modes)):

```
>>> decimal.Decimal('2.5').quantize(
         decimal.Decimal('1'), rounding=decimal.ROUND_HALF_EVEN
)
Decimal('2')

>>> decimal.Decimal('3.5').quantize(
         decimal.Decimal('1'), rounding=decimal.ROUND_HALF_EVEN
)
Decimal('4')

>>> decimal.Decimal('3.5').quantize(
         decimal.Decimal('1'), rounding=decimal.ROUND_HALF_DOWN
)
Decimal('3')

>>> decimal.Decimal('3.5').quantize(
         decimal.Decimal('1'), rounding=decimal.ROUND_HALF_UP
)
Decimal('4')
```